# How to check nested shadow elements using cypress.io

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, shadow-dom

How to locate the search box which is located inside the nested shadow DOMs?

[image]

So far, I have tried few different approaches to locate and below is one of them but it didn't work:

*Locators*:

```
//Shadow roots
const SDW_MAINAPP_G1 = "main-app"
const SDW_VOYAGETOPBAR_G2A = "voyage-topbar"
const SDW_VOYAGEPANEL_G2B = "voyage-float-panel"
const SDW_VESSELLIST_G3B = "voyage-vessel-list"
const SDW_VOYAGEFILTER_G4B1 = "voyage-filter"
const SDW_LISTSORT_G4B2 = "voyage-vessel-list-sort"

//Left Panel - Search Box
const INP_SEARCH_VESSEL = "#filter"
```

*Actual code:*

```
class SearchComponents {
    static validateSearchBar() {
         cy.get(SDW_MAINAPP_G1)
        .shadow()
        .find(SDW_VOYAGEPANEL_G2B)
        .find(SDW_VESSELLIST_G3B)
        .find(SDW_VOYAGEFILTER_G4B1)
        .find(INP_SEARCH_VESSEL)
        .should('be.visible')
        .should('be.enabled')
    }
   //...
   }
```

*Error in Test Runner:*
[image]

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: Added the error screenshot.

Comment: Did you try adding `includeShadowDom: true` to cypress.json? This might save you having to add `.shadow()` at every level.

Comment: It works now after updating this, Can you add it to your answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nested shadow-root's make it difficult to pinpoint where the `.shadow()` command should be added, but you can enable shadow DOM searches globally in [config](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Global) (cypress.json)

> **includeShadowDom**
>
> Whether to traverse shadow DOM boundaries and include elements within the shadow DOM in the results of query commands (e.g. cy.get())

**cypress.json**

```
{
  ...
  includeShadowDom: true
}
```

Comment: There are few more shadow roots at the top., above solution will not work and I have tested also.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. Have never tested so many shadow-roots! Will check it out and amend.

Comment: It doesn't work for me with nested components.

Answer (score 1):

In Cypress v13 there are four options for handling nested shadow DOM

- Globally as mentioned above, but in `cypress.config.js` see [Global Options](https://docs-vercel.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Options)
- In the context or test level

  ```js
  decribe('my context', {includeShadowDom:true}, () => {
    test('my test', {includeShadowDom:true}, () => {
  ```
- Inline, in the command sequence

  ```js
  cy.get(SDW_MAINAPP_G1).shadow()
    .find(SDW_VOYAGEPANEL_G2B).shadow()
  ```
- Inline in the command options

  ```js
  cy.get(SDW_MAINAPP_G1, {includeShadowDom:true})
    .find(SDW_VOYAGEPANEL_G2B, {includeShadowDom:true})
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For nested shadow dom elements you need to first get the shadow element then call the `find` method on it:

```
 cy.get('parent')
     .shadow()
     .find('child')
     .shadow()
     .find('grandchild')
     .should('exist');
```